# problems to insert a list of a query to a combobox

Tags: java, javafx

When debugging I observe the query results in the list receives all values ​​from the database, but in my controller only the last record of my list appears.
I already noticed the problem is in my controller but I have no idea how to solve it.  I think the problem is when I go through my list.

my DAO:

```
    List<Departamento> departamentos = new ArrayList();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM departamentos";
    try {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
       Departamento departamento = new Departamento();
       departamento.setId_departamento(rs.getInt("id_departamentos"));
       departamento.setNome_setor(rs.getString("nome_setor"));
       departamentos.add(departamento);
    }
    ps.close();
    rs.close();
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DepartamentoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return departamentos;
}
```

my controller

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox<Departamento> cbDepart;
private ObservableList<Departamento> obsDepartamentos;
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    DepartamentoDAO dao = new DepartamentoDAO();
    for(Departamento d: dao.read()){
       obsDepartamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(d);
       cbDepart.setItems(obsDepartamentos);
    }
}
```

my model:

```
public class Departamento {

private int id_departamento, idchefe;
private String nome_setor;

public Departamento(int id_departamento, int idchefe, String nome_setor) {
    this.id_departamento = id_departamento;
    this.idchefe = idchefe;
    this.nome_setor = nome_setor;
}

public Departamento(String nome_setor) {
    this.nome_setor = nome_setor;
}

public Departamento(int id_departamento) {
    this.id_departamento = id_departamento;
}

public Departamento(int id_departamento, String nome_setor) {
    this.id_departamento = id_departamento;
    this.nome_setor = nome_setor;
}

public Departamento() {
}

public int getIdchefe() {
    return idchefe;
}

public void setIdchefe(int idchefe) {
    this.idchefe = idchefe;
}

public int getId_departamento() {
    return id_departamento;
}

public void setId_departamento(int id_departamento) {
    this.id_departamento = id_departamento;
}

public String getNome_setor() {
    return nome_setor;
}

public void setNome_setor(String nome_setor) {
    this.nome_setor = nome_setor;
}

public String toString() {
    return getNome_setor();
}
}

DepartamentoDAO dao = new DepartamentoDAO();
for(Departamento d: dao.read()){
   obsDepartamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(d);
   cbDepart.setItems(obsDepartamentos);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add one item to list and then assign it to `cbDepart` so the only last item is displayed, so you need to first `populate the list` then assign it at the end.

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox<Departamento> cbDepart;
private ObservableList<Departamento> obsDepartamentos;
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    DepartamentoDAO dao = new DepartamentoDAO();
    obsDepartamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for(Departamento d: dao.read()){
       obsDepartamentos.add(d);
    }
    cbDepart.setItems(obsDepartamentos);
}
```

**OR** simply:

```
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        DepartamentoDAO dao = new DepartamentoDAO();
        obsDepartamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dao.read());
        cbDepart.setItems(obsDepartamentos);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a new ArrayList during every loop.

Instead of

```
DepartamentoDAO dao = new DepartamentoDAO();
for(Departamento d: dao.read()){
   obsDepartamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(d);
   cbDepart.setItems(obsDepartamentos);
}
```

try

```
DepartamentoDAO dao = new DepartamentoDAO();
obsDepartamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dao.read());
cbDepart.setItems(obsDepartamentos);
```